# Wordpress site is using many connections to mysql

Tags: mysql, wordpress

We have a website running on Wordpress which connects to mySQL database. Wordpress is using many connections, more than 100 and it is not closing them. We tried to close the connection inside the destructor of wordpress db connection. It has helped to some extent, but the connection count is still high. When 3 people connect the site, the connections count is going above 100. Can anyone help us in troubleshooting the issue?

We are using mySQL 5.6 and WordPress 3.9.1

Answer (score 0):

Install the [Wordpress DB Driver](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-db-driver/), set to PDO, and add [PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php) to your initial connection constructor. This will use the same connection for all subsequent connections that connect using the same credentials.